# Seating problem: N tables with N people at each table

Tags: co.combinatorics

There are N tables at a party seating N people each, for a total of N^2 people. Every seat is initially empty.

At each round, every person must sit with a new group of people. If each person were given a number, they would need to see unique numbers at their table every round - numbers they have seen in previous rounds also count.

Question: **How many rounds can occur before a person sees a duplicate?**

The upper bound is (N^2 - 1) / (N - 1) = (N + 1) rounds trivially if you consider the problem from one person's perspective.

For N = 2 (4 people, 2 tables of 2) it is correct:

AB CD
AC BD
AD BC

Is there a general formula for this maximum number of rounds, or is it as obvious as I have written?

**Inspiration**: I was at a workshop with 36 people around 6 identical tables; at the end of each intermission, we were encouraged to sit with entirely new people.

Comment: Just to add some language in case it helps you Google, we can say we’re starting with a complete graph on $n^2$ vertices, and we have a sequence of partitions of the vertices $P_1, P_2, \dots$ where each $P_i$ has $n$ parts of size $n$, and we are wondering how long the sequence can be before the induced subgraph on $P_j$ shares an edge with $P_i$ for $i < j$.

Comment: This is the $S(2,n,n^2)$ Steiner system, see https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SteinerSystem.html for a construction

Comment: I see someone went to Oberwolfach recently ;)

Comment: If N is a prime power then you can achieve the maximum. Let F be a field with N elements, label the points (x,y) for (x,y) in F^2. On the first day, seat people with the same x-value together, then the same x+y value, then the same x+2y value, and so on for x+ky values with each k in F. That's |F| many days; on the last day, seat people by y value.

Comment: @PeterWu It seems slightly harder then that? You also need to group the $n^2$ blocks into $n$ collections of $n$, one for each day. Unless I am missing something.

Comment: PS I don't know why people have voted to close this, it is a perfectly reasonable question about block designs.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I at least voted to close because I saw this as dealing with affine planes, which I thought I remembered as well-understood enough that this would not be research-level. I realize, on second inspection, that less is known than I had thought (and that the question of whether an affine plane even exists for non-prime-power orders is, in fact, open), and so have retracted my close flag.

Comment: @AchimKrause: just recording here that the "Oberwolfach problem" refers to something similar, but different (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oberwolfach_problem )

Comment: @DavidESpeyer Yes, you are right. I just see there is a disjoint condition and why the affine plane failed to give the desired construction for N=6.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I agree. This looks like another case where people vote to close without knowing how to solve the problem.

Answer (score 9):

It is possible to achieve $N+1$ days if and only if there is a [finite projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane#Finite_projective_planes) with $N^2+N+1$ points.

**Given the plane:** Choose a special line $L_{\infty}$ in the plane. Let the $N+1$ points on $L_{\infty}$ be $(D_1, D_2, \dots, D_{N+1})$; these will index the days of the conference. Let the $N^2$ points not on $L_{\infty}$ be $(P_1, P_2, \ldots, P_{N^2})$, these will index the people. For each $D_k$, there are $N$ lines through $D_k$ other then $L_{\infty}$; each of these lines contains $N$ of the $P_i$'s. Use this seating arrangement on day $k$.
Since every pair $(P_i, P_j)$ is on a unique line, and that unique line intersect $L_{\infty}$ at a unique $D_k$, there is a unique day on which $i$ and $j$ sit together.

This construction is easily reversible: **Given the seating arrangement**, let the points of our underlying plane be $N^2$ points $P_i$ for the people and $N+1$ points $D_k$ for the days. Define a line to consist of $D_k$, together with all of the $P_i$ for people $i$ who sat together on day $k$. Also, add one more line $\{ D_1, D_2, \ldots, D_{N+1} \}$. It is straightforward to check that this obeys the axioms of a projective plane.

As the Wikipedia link above says, projective planes exist whenever $N$ is a prime power, and have been proved not to exist for $N=6$, $10$. The particular case of $N=6$, which you raise, is impossible. Moral: Conferences should be $5$ days long, not $7$ !

---

Solving this problem for $d$ days is equivalent to constructing $d-2$ [mutually orthogonal $N \times N$ Latin squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutually_orthogonal_Latin_squares), which we'll call $L_3$, $L_4$, ..., $L_d$. So **your problem is equivalent to finding the maximum number of $N \times N$ mutually orthogonal magic squares**. See [OEIS sequence A001438](https://oeis.org/A001438) and the references there.

Here is **how to go from MOLS to a seating plan**.
Label the people by pairs $(i,j)$ with $1 \leq i,j \leq N$. On the first day, people with the same $i$-coordinate eat together. On the second day, people with the same $j$ coordinate eat together. On day $k$, for $k \geq 3$, group people according to the entries of the corresponding cells in $L_k$.

This construction is easily reversible: **Given a seating arrangement**, number the tables arbitrarily on each day. The $(i,j)$ entry in $L_k$ is given by finding the unique person who ate at table $i$ on day $1$ and table $j$ on day $2$, and writing down the number of the table where they ate on day $k$.

This means that your conference choose uniquely poorly in taking $N=6$! It is possible to achieve $4$ days for every $N$ **except** $N=2$ and $N=6$. See:

*Bose, R. C.; Shrikhande, S. S.; Parker, E. T.*, [**Further results on the construction of mutually orthogonal latin squares and the falsity of Euler’s conjecture**](https://doi.org/10.4153/CJM-1960-016-5), Can. J. Math. 12, 189-203 (1960). [ZBL0093.31905](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0093.31905).

If $N$ is odd, the solution for $4$ days is particularly easy to describe: Seat the people by $i$-coordinate on day $1$, by $j$-coordinate on day $2$, by $i+j$ on day $3$ and by $i+2j$ on day $4$.

More generally, if $p$ is the smallest prime divisor of $N$, then I believe that we can achieve $p+1$ days by using $i$, $j$, $i+j$, $i+2j$, ..., $i+(p-1)j$. I also have a construction which gets $\min(p_i^{e_i})+1$ days, when $N = p_1^{e_1} p_2^{e_2} \cdots p_r^{e_r}$ is the prime factorization of $N$, but I'm going to hold off writing it up.

Comment: Remark: I wrote this answer using the standard description of mutually orthogonal Latin squares, but the definition I prefer is that having $d-2$ MOLS's is the same as having an $N^2$ element subset of $[N]^d$ which projects bijectively onto every $2$-dimensional coordinate plane. From this perspective, the subset is given by, for each person, listing the sequence of $d$ tables at which they have sat.